# how to update view in UI thread from worker thread

Tags: android-webview

I have two threads running one id UI and other is worker thread. Worker thread continuously reads on port for some data from server, when appears I need to update my webview in UI thread. Worker thread again continues to read and never ends. Plz suggest how to accomplish this??

it may be likely as 'signals in C++' which causes a method in called thread to be invoked..!!
I tried: 1)As running worker thread on UI (runOnUIThread)may degrade UI webview performance, and if I put the thread on sleep it may miss data appeared at port when sleeping..(i m not sure!)
2)using Handler, I hav to specify time before calling thread again n again which may cause to miss data if appeared on port as like sleep().
3)Having a separate thread in same class,it gives: any other thread cant update view of main UI thread.

Plz help.. :(

Comment: Please suggest..do runOnUI affect the performance of UI thread??.....as I have a Ui thread which sud not hang at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like creating a Handler object and then using the post() method is what you need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: using Hadler object and than using post(), slows down the performance of UI thread very badly, as in runnable it hangs on reading data from server(in.readline). Same as with runOnUiThread.

I also tried observer pattern in JAVA, but alas :(
1. I have two threads 'worker' and 'UI' thread.
2. worker keep on waiting for data from server, when gets it notifies to UI thread.
3. On update UI Toast a msg on screen.
Step 3 is problem as it says 
: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I have a UI thread and a few threads that do backend serverices.  I use the observer Pattern to have the services update the UI and to do so I have the update method in a new thread and call `runOnUiThread()` to have it update the UI.  It seems to work well for something quick.  If you want something better than a quick band-aid I would suggest reading [this android threading guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) from Google and trying to incorporate it with your design.